# Huge framerate drops in an empty scene - what is going on?

Tags: unity, performance, ios, iphone, lag

I would really appreciate you guys helping me out with a baffling problem I am experiencing. I have a near-empty scene. It has one object, i.e., a ball bouncing in it, targeting 60FPS.

I am deploying this to iOS to run on iPhones and it works. Lo and behold, the ball bounces at 60FPS. Here it is running:

[image]

Below you can see it running in the profiler. Indeed, it renders within 16.6ms keeping the smooth 60FPS.

[image]

Okay, so here is the problem. As soon as I touch my screen on the iPhone, the framerate immediately halves to 30FPS causing significant lag in the game. Why is this happening?

You can see below in the profiler what happens when the screen is touched. For some bizarre reason, it is taking twice as long to render. It stays like this for a second, and then resumes to 60FPS. If I touch again, this reoccurs every time the screen is touched.

[image]

Please, someone tell me what is going on here?! Why is this happening? I was experiencing this in my real game and I thought it was an issue with my game's complexity. So I created this new, empty project and the problem is still happening. So clearly it has nothing to do with my game or its logic.

Below are some details on the versions I am using and the devices I tested this on:

Unity Version: 2020.3.48

- iPhone 14 Pro (iOS 17.3.1): Issue occurs
- iPhone 14 Pro Max (iOS 17.3.1): Issue occurs
- iPhone SE 3rd Gen (iOS 17.3.1): Issue occurs
- iPhone SE 1st Gen (iOS 15.8): Issue does not occur!
- Google Pixel 7a (Android 14): Issue does not occur!

As you can see, this issue occurs on iPhone and not on Android. Weirdly, the only iPhone that did not experience this problem is the first-gen SE, which maintains a smooth 60 FPS. The others listed all experience this issue! I thought it might be ProMotion related but it happens on the third-gen SE too which is not ProMotion.

If someone could resolve this I would appreciate it more than you can imagine. It is causing horrible lag issues whenever the player touches the screen and interacts with my game on iPhone.

Comment: I think a few more details might help people debug. Is this the profiler running on the phone? Or in the editor? What is your bouncing ball script? Are you building in debug or release mode? Did you try another Unity version?

Comment: Also, many iPhones limit for to 30fps by default. Perhaps it’s actually supposed to be 30fps based on the settings you have?

Comment: It is definitely not supposed to be 30fps because I have set the Application.targetFrameRate to 60fps. And as mentioned it runs 60fps except for when the screen is touched, it then lags for a second and returns to 60fps. Profiler is running in the editor with phone connected via USB. It is built as a development build. I have not tried another Unity version, I could try it but it would require me to upgrade my real project which I want to avoid if possible. The ball bouncing script is just a few lines of very simple code, I can post it later if it helps but I’m not sure how that would help.

Comment: Also if I set the target frame-rate to 120fps (for iPhone 14 Pro) it runs nice and smooth at 120fps. But when I touch the screen it halves again to about 59fps, stays there for a second and then returns to 120fps again.

Comment: What happens when you dont set a target framerate?

Comment: If I don't set the target framerate it just runs at a choppy 30fps all the time, which is what I do not want. I need it to run at 60fps continuously. It's no good if it halves to 30fps whenever the screen is touched.

Comment: The profiler has a high performance cost. Do you still get performance issues in a release build without the profiler? Is there any input-handling code on any object in your scene?

Comment: Have you tried the [guided access possible fix](https://www.reddit.com/r/geometrydash/comments/xny8qf/comment/jcg09c2/)? I'm not an iOS user, so I can't verify it.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to make any difference. Besides, that's a pretty absurd fix because how can I put that responsibility on the player and expect them to know that?

Comment: This seems to be an Apple problem, but someone thinks they found a work-around that might work since you are targeting 60fps ( https://forum.unity.com/threads/frame-rate-halves-when-tapping-the-display.1425075/#post-8959434 ) disclaimer: I don't know unity nor iOs at all

Comment: Thanks but that does not work, I already tried it.